# solutions for Diophantine $2x^3+1=y^3$

Tags: number-theory

Consider Diophantine equation $2x^3+1=y^3$

There are two solutions  $$x=(0,-1), \, y=(1,-1)  $$

Are there anymore integer solutions for $x$ and $y$?

I've tried the following argument but am not satisfied with it.

Identity:    $$[(B^3)(x^6)+3(B^2)(x^3)+3(B)]x^3+1=(Bx^3+1)^3$$

Looks like:  $$[        2                  ]x^3+1=(  y   )^3$$

Let  $[(B^3)(x^6)+3(B^2)(x^3)+3(B)]=2$ and $(Bx^3+1)=y$

Since $2$ divides $B$ we get possible values for $B$ are  $$B=\{-2,-1,1,2\}$$
Testing the $B$ set in equation $$[(B^3)(x^6)+3(B^2)(x^3)+3(B)]=2$$ we can see that the only possible integer solution is $B=2$ and $x=-1$ and so $y=-1$.

The other solution is trivial $x=0,\,y=1$. So from this argument there are no other integer solutions for $x$ and $y$.

My problem with the above argument is that by me saying:

"Let  $[(B^3)(x^6)+3(B^2)(x^3)+3(B)]=2$ and $(Bx^3+1)=y$" 
I am indirectly saying from the start that there and no other solutions.

What I would have to do is prove that:

1. *all* possible solutions for $y$ are of the form $Bx^3+1$
   and
2. equation $[(B^3)(x^6)+3(B^2)(x^3)+3(B)]=2$ is true for all possible solutions for $x$

But I cannot prove it.

thank you

Comment: Observation $$(y-1,y^2+y+1)=(y-1,3)$$

Comment: It is $$(y-x)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)